# OpenMP computation errors

Tags: fortran, openmp, computation

When I enable the OpenMP lines in the following code, I do not often get the correct solutions (so I suspect something is wrong with the parallelization). I have gone through the code over and over again, yet I still could not find where is the problem.

```
!$OMP PARALLEL SHARED(w, h, u, v, hu, hv, d)                                &
!$OMP& SHARED(nxw, nyw)                                                     &
!$OMP& SHARED(rx, ry, rxg, ryg)                                             &
!$OMP& SHARED(ispans, ispane, jspans, jspane, chunk)                        &
!$OMP& SHARED(a)                                                            &
!$OMP& PRIVATE(i, j, it)                                                    &
!$OMP& PRIVATE(ip1, im1, im2, jp1, jm1, jm2, iu1, jv1)                      &
!$OMP& PRIVATE(ww, hh, uu, vv, hu1, hu2, hv1, hv2, dd, df)                  &
!$OMP& PRIVATE(xvv, xuu, xve, xue, advx, advy)                              &
!$OMP& PRIVATE(c, dwdt_i, dwdt_f, dwdt, ref, coef)                          &
!$OMP& PRIVATE(du, dv, noflux)
ompstart = OMP_GET_WTIME()
do it = 1, itlast
    !$OMP DO SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC, CHUNK)
    do j = 2, nyw-1
        do i = 2, nxw-1
            if (d(i,j) .gt. rpmax) then
                ww = w(i,j,1) - rx*(u(i,j,1) - u(i-1,j,1))                  &
                                - ry*(v(i,j,1) - v(i,j-1,1))
                if (abs(ww) .lt. eps) ww = 0.0
                hh = ww + d(i,j)
                if (hh .ge. gx) then
                    h(i,j,2) = hh
                    w(i,j,2) = ww
                else
                    h(i,j,2) = 0.0
                    w(i,j,2) = -d(i,j)
                end if
            else
                h(i,j,2) = 0.0
                w(i,j,2) = -d(i,j)
            end if
        end do
    end do
    !$OMP END DO

    !$OMP DO SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC, CHUNK)
    do j = 1, nyw
        do i = 1, nxw-1
            hu1 = 0.25*(h(i,j,2) + h(i+1,j,2) + h(i,j,1) + h(i+1,j,1))
            hu2 = 0.50*(h(i,j,2) + h(i+1,j,2))
            if (hu1 .lt. gx) hu1 = 0.0
            if (hu2 .lt. gx) hu2 = 0.0
            hu(i,j,1) = hu1
            hu(i,j,2) = hu2
        end do
    end do
    !$OMP END DO

    !$OMP DO SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC, CHUNK)
    do j = 1, nyw-1
        do i = 1, nxw
            hv1 = 0.25*(h(i,j,2) + h(i,j+1,2) + h(i,j,1) + h(i,j+1,1))
            hv2 = 0.50*(h(i,j,2) + h(i,j+1,2))
            if (hv1 .lt. gx) hv1 = 0.0
            if (hv2 .lt. gx) hv2 = 0.0
            hv(i,j,1) = hv1
            hv(i,j,2) = hv2
        end do
    end do
    !$OMP END DO

    !$OMP DO SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC, CHUNK)
    do i = 1, nxw-1
        ip1 = i+1
        im1 = i-1
        if (im1 .le. 1) im1 = 1
        if (ip1 .ge. nxw-1) ip1 = nxw-1
        do j = 1, nyw
            noflux = 0
            jp1 = j+1
            jm1 = j-1
            jv1 = j
            if (jm1 .le. 1) jm1 = 1
            if (jp1 .ge. nyw) jp1 = nyw
            if (jv1 .ge. nyw-1) jv1 = nyw-1

            du = 0.5*(d(i,j) + d(i+1,j))
            if (d(i,j) .le. rpmax .or. du .le. rpmax) then
                u(i,j,2) = 0.0
                noflux = 1
            else                
                if (h(i,j,2) .gt. gx .and. h(i+1,j,2) .gt. gx) then         
                    dd = hu(i,j,2)
                    df = hu(i,j,1)
                else if (h(i,j,2) .gt. gx .and. h(i+1,j,2) .le. gx          &
                           .and. d(i+1,j) + w(i,j,2) .gt. gx) then
                    dd = 0.5*h(i,j,2)
                    df = dd
                else if (h(i,j,2) .le. gx .and. h(i+1,j,2) .gt. gx          &
                           .and. d(i,j) + w(i+1,j,2) .gt. gx) then
                    dd = 0.5*h(i+1,j,2)
                    df = dd
                else 
                    u(i,j,2) = 0.0
                    noflux = 1
                end if

                if (dd .lt. gx) then
                    u(i,j,2) = 0.0
                    noflux = 1
                end if
            end if

            if (noflux .ne. 1) then
                xvv = 0.25*(v(i,jv1,1) + v(i+1,jv1,1) +                     &
                            v(i,jm1,1) + v(i+1,jm1,1))
                uu = u(i,j,1) - rxg*dd*(w(i+1,j,2) - w(i,j,2))

                if (hu(i,j,1) .ge. gx .and.                                 &
                    (i .gt. ispans .and. i .lt. ispane .and.                &
                    j .gt. jspans .and. j .lt. jspane)) then
                    advx = 0.0
                    advy = 0.0

                    if (u(i,j,1) .lt. zero) then
                        if (hu(ip1,j,1) .lt. gx .or.                        &
                            h(ip1,j,2) .lt. gx) then
                            advx = rx*(-u(i,j,1)**2.0/hu(i,j,1))
                        else
                            advx = rx*(u(ip1,j,1)**2.0/hu(ip1,j,1)          &
                                        - u(i,j,1)**2.0/hu(i,j,1))
                        end if
                    else
                        if (hu(im1,j,1) .lt. gx .or.                        &
                            h(i,j,2) .lt. gx) then
                            advx = rx*(u(i,j,1)**2.0/hu(i,j,1))
                        else
                            advx = rx*(u(i,j,1)**2.0/hu(i,j,1)              &
                                        - u(im1,j,1)**2.0/hu(im1,j,1))
                        end if
                    end if

                    if (xvv .lt. zero) then
                        if (h(i,jp1,2) .lt. gx .or.                         &
                            h(ip1,jp1,2) .lt. gx) then
                            advy = ry*(-u(i,j,1)*xvv/hu(i,j,1))
                        else if (hu(i,jp1,1) .lt. gx) then
                            advy = ry*(-u(i,j,1)*xvv/hu(i,j,1))
                        else
                            xve = 0.25*(v(i,jp1,1) + v(ip1,jp1,1)           &
                                            + v(i,j,1) + v(ip1,j,1))
                            advy = ry*(u(i,jp1,1)*xve/hu(i,jp1,1)           &
                                            - u(i,j,1)*xvv/hu(i,j,1))
                        end if
                    else
                        if (h(i,jm1,2) .lt. gx .or.                         &
                            h(ip1,jm1,2) .lt. gx) then
                            advy = ry*(u(i,j,1)*xvv/hu(i,j,1))
                        else if (hu(i,jm1,1) .lt. gx) then
                            advy = ry*(u(i,j,1)*xvv/hu(i,j,1))
                        else
                            jm2 = j-2
                            if (jm2 .le. 1) jm2 = 1
                            xve = 0.25*(v(i,jm1,1) + v(ip1,jm1,1)           &
                                            + v(i,jm2,1) + v(ip1,jm2,1))
                            advy = ry*(u(i,j,1)*xvv/hu(i,j,1)               &
                                        - u(i,jm1,1)*xve/hu(i,jm1,1))
                        end if
                    end if

                    C = SQRT(GRAV*H(I,J,2))
                    DWDT_F = 0.08*C
                    DWDT_I = 0.65*C
                    DWDT = ABS(W(I,J,2) - W(I,J,1))/DELT
                    IF (DWDT .GT. DWDT_F) THEN
                        REF = (DWDT - DWDT_F)/(DWDT_I - DWDT_F)
                        A = 1.0
                        COEF = EXP(-A*REF)
                        ADVX = COEF*ADVX
                        ADVY = COEF*ADVY
                    END IF
                    uu = uu - advx - advy
                end if
                if (abs(uu) .lt. eps) uu = 0.0
                if (uu .gt. 20.0*dd) uu = 20.0*dd
                if (uu .lt. -20.0*dd) uu = -20.0*dd
                u(i,j,2) = uu
            else
                u(i,j,2) = 0.0
            end if
        end do
    end do
    !$OMP END DO

    !$OMP DO SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC, CHUNK)
    do i = 1, nxw
        ip1 = i+1
        im1 = i-1
        iu1 = i
        if (im1 .le. 1) im1 = 1
        if (ip1 .ge. nxw) ip1 = nxw
        if (iu1 .ge. nxw-1) iu1 = nxw-1
        do j = 1, nyw-1
            noflux = 0
            jp1 = j+1
            jm1 = j-1
            if (jm1 .le. 1) jm1 = 1
            if (jp1 .ge. nyw-1) jp1 = nyw-1

            dv = 0.5*(d(i,j) + d(i,j+1))
            if (d(i,j) .le. rpmax .or. dv .le. rpmax) then
                v(i,j,2) = 0.0
                noflux = 1
            else
                if (h(i,j,2) .gt. gx .and. h(i,j+1,2) .gt. gx) then
                    dd = hv(i,j,2)
                    df = hv(i,j,1)
                else if (h(i,j,2) .gt. gx .and. h(i,j+1,2) .le. gx          &
                            .and. d(i,j+1) + w(i,j,2) .gt. gx) then
                    dd = 0.5*h(i,j,2)
                    df = dd
                else if (h(i,j,2) .le. gx .and. h(i,j+1,2) .gt. gx          &
                            .and. d(i,j) + w(i,j+1,2) .gt. gx) then
                    dd = 0.5*h(i,j+1,2)
                    df = dd
                else
                    v(i,j,2) = 0.0
                    noflux = 1
                end if

                if (dd .lt. gx) then
                    v(i,j,2) = 0.0
                    noflux = 1
                end if
            end if

            if (noflux .ne. 1) then
                xuu = 0.25*(u(iu1,j,1) + u(iu1,jp1,1) +                     &
                            u(im1,j,1) + u(im1,jp1,1))
                vv = v(i,j,1) - ryg*dd*(w(i,j+1,2) - w(i,j,2))

                if (hv(i,j,1) .ge. gx .and.                                 &
                    (i .gt. ispans .and. i .lt. ispane .and.                &
                    j .gt. jspans .and. j .lt. jspane)) then
                    advx = 0.0
                    advy = 0.0

                    if (v(i,j,1) .lt. zero) then
                        if (hv(i,jp1,1) .lt. gx .or.                        &
                            h(i,jp1,2) .lt. gx) then
                            advy = ry*(-v(i,j,1)**2.0/hv(i,j,1))
                        else
                            advy = ry*(v(i,jp1,1)**2.0/hv(i,jp1,1)          &
                                        - v(i,j,1)**2.0/hv(i,j,1))
                        end if
                    else
                        if (hv(i,jm1,1) .lt. gx .or.                        &
                            h(i,j,2) .lt. gx) then
                            advy = ry*(v(i,j,1)**2.0/hv(i,j,1))
                        else
                            advy = ry*(v(i,j,1)**2.0/hv(i,j,1)              &
                                        - v(i,jm1,1)**2.0/hv(i,jm1,1))
                        end if
                    end if

                    if (xuu .lt. zero) then
                        if (h(ip1,j,2) .lt. gx .or.                         &
                            h(ip1,jp1,2) .lt. gx) then
                            advx = rx*(-v(i,j,1)*xuu/hv(i,j,1))
                        else if (hv(ip1,j,1) .lt. gx) then
                            advx = rx*(-v(i,j,1)*xuu/hv(i,j,1))
                        else
                            xue = 0.25*(u(ip1,j,1) + u(ip1,jp1,1)           &
                                            + u(i,j,1) + u(i,jp1,1))
                            advx = rx*(v(ip1,j,1)*xue/hv(ip1,j,1)           &
                                            - v(i,j,1)*xuu/hv(i,j,1))
                        end if
                    else
                        if (h(im1,j,2) .lt. gx .or.                         &
                            h(im1,jp1,2) .lt. gx) then
                            advx = rx*(v(i,j,1)*xuu/hv(i,j,1))
                        else if (hv(im1,j,1) .lt. gx) then
                            advx = rx*(v(i,j,1)*xuu/hv(i,j,1))
                        else
                            im2 = i-2
                            if (im2 .le. 1) im2 = 1
                            xue = 0.25*(u(im1,j,1) + u(im1,jp1,1)           &
                                            + u(im2,j,1) + u(im2,jp1,1))
                            advx = rx*(v(i,j,1)*xuu/hv(i,j,1)               &
                                            - v(im1,j,1)*xue/hv(im1,j,1))
                        end if
                    end if

                    C = SQRT(GRAV*H(I,J,2))
                    DWDT_F = 0.08*C
                    DWDT_I = 0.65*C
                    DWDT = ABS(W(I,J,2) - W(I,J,1))/DELT
                    IF (DWDT .GT. DWDT_F) THEN
                        REF = (DWDT - DWDT_F)/(DWDT_I - DWDT_F)
                        A = 1.0
                        COEF = EXP(-A*REF)
                        ADVX = COEF*ADVX
                        ADVY = COEF*ADVY
                    END IF
                    vv = vv - advx - advy
                end if
                if (abs(vv) .lt. eps) vv = 0.0
                if (vv .gt. 20.0*dd) vv = 20.0*dd
                if (vv .lt. -20.0*dd) vv = -20.0*dd
                v(i,j,2) = vv
            else
                v(i,j,2) = 0.0
            end if
        end do
    end do
    !$OMP END DO

    !$OMP SINGLE
    call tuna_openbc
    !$OMP END SINGLE

    !$OMP SINGLE
    call tuna_update
    !$OMP END SINGLE
end do
ompend = OMP_GET_WTIME()
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

Above code is the computation part (it is a lengthy code). I make sure all the loop counters `it, i, j`, and dummy loop counters `ip1, im1, jp1, jm1`, etc are set as private. Also all the dummy variables `ww, uu, vv`, etc are all set as private. I am not sure where I did wrong. All my variables and constants are declared in a module as shown below.

```
real, parameter :: gx = 1.0e-5
real, parameter :: eps = 1.0e-10
real, parameter :: zero = 0.0
real, parameter :: rpmax = -20.0
real, parameter :: grav = 9.807

real, dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: w
real, dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: h
real, dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: u
real, dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: v
real, dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: hu
real, dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: hv
real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: d

integer :: nxw, nyw
real :: delx, dely, delt
```

Please share if you find something is not right.

Comment: Yes, it should be "When I **enable** the OpenMP lines...". I am working on privatize the variables `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICS, your code exposes two oddities:

- The variable `a` is declared `shared` whereas it looks like it should have been declared `private`
- The two variables `ompstart` and `ompend` should probably be initialised outside of the `parallel` region. Otherwise, all threads will try to update them concurrently.

All other variables look fine to me. In addition, I tried to check for potential dependencies between various indexes of `u` and `v`, but didn't spot any. So maybe declaring `a` `private` might be enough to fix your code.

Comment: I took away `a = 1.0`, and change `coef = exp(-a*ref)` to `coef = exp(-1.0*ref)`. So far it works fine for two benchmark simulations. I do not quite understand why `a` should be private. For example, `uu = u(i,j,1) - rxg*dd*(w(i+1,j,2) - w(i,j,2))`, `rxg` can be shared among all threads, because it is a constant I declare and initialize before entering `OMP` region, but for `a = 1.0`, I initialize in a `OMP DO SCHEDULE` loop, hence it should be `private`. Am I right?

Comment: well, I hadn't see that `a` was only assigned to 1 anyway... So semantically, `a` needs to be private because it is modified inside the `parallel` region; but realistically, it should have been assigned to  outside the `parallel` region and kept `shared`... If really that is why the code had issues, then really that is weird. (complier's black magic maybe)

Comment: Alright, I will check the code again by passing all benchmark cases. I am using Intel Visual Fortran on Windows, but it is a old version (because gfortran seems slower). Also, this parallelized code produces simulation results slightly different from the serial code, in terms of number (about 0.05% relative errors), is it normal?

Comment: Hi @Gilles, after testing several benchmark cases, the problem still persists. But, after I re-compiling the code again without any changes, it will work just fine. If I compile without OpenMP, it always works fine, but with OpenMP, sometimes it fails to give me the proper solutions.

Comment: well, I rechecked the code as much as I could and didn't find anything wrong. The only things I can encourage you to do are: 1/ use `implicit none` in your code; 2/ use `default(none)` in your OpenMP parallel directive; 3/ enable bound checking by your compiler. And fix any warning and / or error reported. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @Gilles, I found and solved the problems using your suggestion. Thank you very much. The problem were 1/ `delt` was not declared as `SHARED` and 2/ the bound of variable `v` exceeded its declared size. So I think it is a good habit to always use `DEFAULT (none)` and bound checking. I learned few things again from you, thank you.